# iCloud Coredata store not loading - iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios8

I am trying to add iCloud to an existing app and I was initially testing on simulator and things were working fine without any problems at all.
This included syncing and migration and all.

Now when I want to test it on the actual test device Local store is loading perfectly while iCloud store doesn't seems to be loading at all.
There are no errors and neither loading is successful.

I tried debugging and found that the basic data that I am passing is correct but unable to understand anything else.

Has anyone encountered this?

Any pointers in this would be much appreciated.

Below is the debugging log:

```
+[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant createActualStoreURLForStoreURL:localPeerID:containerIdentifier:andStoreName:](3877): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Created actual store url: file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~9A839BAC-552E-4D3C-AE09-BCAB94B33261/<AppName>/EF117F77-637A-4BD1-9F39-E01FB82B96F1/store/iCloud~com~kapdevelopers~BabyBook
for url: file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~kapdevelopers~BabyBook/
2014-09-25 08:06:16.523 OurBabyBookPro[2668:1135651] -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant validateOptionsWithError:](524): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquitySetupAssistant: 0x13f500e00>
    options: {
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey = <appName>;
    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey = "iCloud.com.<companyName>.<appName>";
    NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption = 0;
}
    psc: <NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x1702675c0>
    store: (null)
    storeURL: file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~<companyName>~<appName>/
    actualStoreURL: file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~9A839BAC-552E-4D3C-AE09-BCAB94B33261/<AppName>/EF117F77-637A-4BD1-9F39-E01FB82B96F1/store/iCloud~com~<companyName>~<appName>
    storeMetadata: (null)
    storeKV: (null)
    storeFileExists: 0
    storeFileIsReadOnly: 0
    ubiquityEnabled: 1
    ubiquityIdentityToken: <0621b923 47ea009e 2096a49d dd496b0b b6319028>
    ubiquityRootURL: (null)
    ubiquityRootSubpath: iCloud.com.<companyName>.<appName>
    ubiquityName: OurBabyBookPro
    ubiquityContainerIdentifier: (null)
    localPeerID: mobile~9A839BAC-552E-4D3C-AE09-BCAB94B33261
    modelVersionHash: nJexgO_Ru2Mp3vSmn0qQ_15mh77BleLe4xUqnI6cZnM=
    ubiquityRootLocation: (null)
    localRootLocation: (null)
    metaKV: (null)
    baseline: (null)
    baselineFileExists: 0
    hasUploadingBaseline: 0
    monitorBaslineUploadAsync: 0
    didBaselineCopy: 0
    baselineKV: (null)
    hasStoreMetadataFile: 0
    hasStoreMetadataEntry: 0
    hasContainerUUID: 0
    hasContainerUUIDInStore: 0
    needsMetadataRecovery: 0
    localPeerReceipt: (null)
    receiptKV: (null)
    containerIdentifier: (null)
    preStoreContainerUUID: EF117F77-637A-4BD1-9F39-E01FB82B96F1
    usedExistingUUIDMapping: 1
    hasLocalTransactionLogs: 0
    votedOffIsland: 0
    reapUbiquitousLogs: 0
    respondToBaselineRoll: 0
    hasMigrationOptions: 1
    didMigrateBaseline: 0
    storeWasMigrated: 0
    replayLogsSynchronously: 0
    useLocalAccount: 0
    abortSetup: 0
    gotExportNotification: 0
```

Cheers,
Kunjal

Comment: I've also been experiencing this, but haven't found a solution. Did you? It seems a key is `ubiquityContainerIdentifier: (null)` in your output.

Comment: I have tried all options ranging from deleting the iCloud container to creating new one and assignment of multiple cloud containers and use 1 out of it. Also, as you pointed, used 1 container with ubiquityContainerIdentifier = nil...
But haven't found anything as yet...
I would post if i am able to find anything on it.